# Convert string into tuple for django choices for forms.Select

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a string stored in a database as

```
yes:Yes, I agree;no:No, I do not agree
```

I am trying to convert that to something I can use as **mychoices** in the following:

```
widget=forms.Select(choices=mychoices)
```

The following works fine if I hardwire in this fashion, but the values are stored as options in the database in a single field (out of my control).

```
for f in fields:
    # mychoices = f.choices  
    mychoices = (('yes','Yes, I agree'),('no','No, I do not agree'))
    self.fields[f.name] = forms.CharField(label=f.name,
                                            help_text=f.description
                                            widget=forms.Select(choices=mychoices))
```

I've tried a few variations of split on ; and : but can't seem to find the proper way to do this. I get values errors of needing more than one value to unpack, or having too many values to unpack.

There are records with more than 2 options but all in the format:

```
code1:Text to display;code2:Text to display;code3:Text to display...
```

How do I get the **f.choices** into something like **mychoices** as hard coded above?

**EDIT:**
Yes using the following worked (thanks @MauroBaraldi - still too new to get you a publicly viewable upvote, but it's there)

```
for f in fields:
    mychoices = tuple(tuple(c.split(':')) for c in f.choices.split(";"))  
    # mychoices = (('yes','Yes, I agree'),('no','No, I do not agree'))
    self.fields[f.name] = forms.CharField(label=f.name,
                                            help_text=f.description    
                                            widget=forms.Select(choices=mychoices))
```

Comment: @MauroBaraldi I end up with tuple like `>>> ('yes:Yes, I agree', 'no:No, I do not agree')
` but I don't know how to do the double split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you had problems using `split`. Perhaps because you've done this way

```
choices = 'code1:Text to display;code2:Text to display;code3:Text to display'.split(';')
```

Try this way

```
choices = 'code1:Text to display;code2:Text to display;code3:Text to display'.split(';')
choices = [c.split(':') for c in choices]
```

Comment: yes, I think you've got me in the right direction. Testing out with `tuple(tuple(c.split(':')) for c in f.choices.split(";"))` now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#choices)

Comment: Thanks, I am attempting to use the two tuples. I can't seem to get that string into the two tuples properly.